# Error while loading shared libraries: libminiupnpc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I try to run a programm on Ubuntu 16.10 x64, but I get the error:

```
Error while loading shared libraries: libminiupnpc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install the missing package by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev
```

That gives me the following message:

```
libminiupnpc-dev is already the newest version (1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aptitude-common libcwidget3v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libxapian22v5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

So I guess its installed but in the wrong version. I tried to locate the file so I could just rename it or try to make a symbolic link or something, but could not find it on my system.

Any suggestions how to resolve this?